# Visual Studio - The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

When trying to build/run a solution that the rest of my teams is using without issues, I keep getting the following error messages.

- At runtime it throws exception when instantiating the DbContext: "The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid"
- With an inner exception: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed"

With the exact same code/project/configuration, 3 other team mates have no issues with this.

We use VS2013, EF 5.0, Oracle Client for .NET, Windows 7 x64
The connection string:

```
metadata=res://*/BpmModel.csdl|res://*/BpmModel.ssdl|res://*/BpmModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=BpmOracle;PASSWORD=xxxxxxx;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=xxxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

So far we have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling VS2013
- Installing VS2014 Update 4
- Created and recreated the solution and workspace about 3-4 times
- Entity Framework is installed
- TNSNames.ora is correct

Any other things we could try to solve this puzzle?

Comment: do you have the correct provider installed? Maybe you used the EF6 version which is incompatible to the older EF5

Comment: I just double checked and I have EF5 installed. Any other suggestions? I've run out of options.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the issue.
Switching to a 32-bit application in IIS did the trick.

Details:

- Open IIS
- Un-twirl the connections list (Most likely the computer name)
- Click on Application Pools
- For each of the applications listed:

  - Right click >> Advanced Settings
  - Set "Enable 30-Bit Applications" to True

Comment: Enabling 32-bit on IIS solved my issue as well but I had to set the project's Platform target to x86 (in project properties)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your oracle provider registered in your app.config/web.config in the provider section? Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92ceczx1%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/usingoracleprovidersaspnet2/UsingOracleProvidersforASPNet.htm) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem was to add the required configuration in Web.config, installing through **NuGet** the missing package.

Right click your solution or project, click on Manage NuGet packages, and install the missing Oracle reference. This should modify your Web.config with the reference.